# laptop stays stuck at battery icon even when connected to wall plug and charging

Tags: 22.04, power-management, laptop, battery

TLDR!

What is the component that displays the battery icon vs charging icon in the top right part of screen, as well as the percentage charged?

Asking, so as to determine why this part is not detecting wall-plug connection (thought battery is being charged and laptop functions fine).

Details:

Laptop make: MSI Bravo

Laptop is connected to power, and battery is being charged but the icon shows it as being not connected to power and being run on battery.

[image]

The laptop stays charged and that "96%" stays there unchanged. I tried rebooting, plugging power out and back in, no change. When the laptop truly works out of battery (power cable actually disconnected), the battery charge percentage starts dropping, like if it was at 99% before, it will drop to 96%. At this point when I connect the power cable back, the icon stays as when running on battery and percentage stays stuck at the last count..96%. The laptop is being charged. This issue is only on ubuntu side. On windows side, it works fine.

Also, when I goto ubuntu settings app, it shows this..even when power cable is connected and laptop is being charged:
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charging icon display depends on what upower is reporting.
You can check upower by simply typing in terminal.

```
upower -d
```

This will display information regarding your battery and power supply. You check what is reported at the property `state` under `battery`.

Battery state reported in upower could be any one of the following :

- charging
- discharging
- empty
- fully-charged
- pending-charge
- pending-discharge
- unknown

> - If battery->state = 'fully-charged' or 'charging', then charging icon is displayed
> - If battery->state = 'discharging', 'pending-charge' or 'pending-discharge', then discharging icon is displayed.

By your description one possibility could be that charging threshold is applied, which probably is preventing the battery to charge to 100%.

When charging threshold is applied and battery level is above charging threshold value, upower will set battery state to 'pending-charge' (sometimes battery state might report 'discharging' initially in this situation, but in 30 seconds it will change to 'pending-charge'), so in this case the icon displayed will be discharging even though charger is plugged in.

Check your upower battery-state, if it is 'pending-charge', and if it is then disable charging-threshold.

1. You can check and disable charging threshold in bios if setting is available.
2. Lately in kernel 6.4 (I am not sure which exact kernel version),  patch were submitted to support setting of charging threshold for MSI laptops. Depending on the kernel you are using, (or if the patch made it to 22.04) you can change charging threshold using command line or gnome extension. For more detail check https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/device-compatibility/msi

Reply back if the issue is not due to charging threshold , and hopefully someone will guide you further.

Comment: fantastic answer. yes, its indeed "pending-charge". 
And yes, when I was using kernel 6.6.* via mainline, I did not see this issue. Unfortunately nvidia drivers only support 6.2.37 kernel currently with 22.04. So looks like I am stuck with it.
One question, why is charging threshold being applied in bios? Is it for battery safety?

Comment: Keeping battery level at 100% for a long period of time (not in terms of hour, but days) can cause degradation of battery.
Laptop maker has provided a setting that set Charging threshold / limit that will prevent battery from charging above a certain value typically 80%.
This is useful for gamer and office user, who run their laptop **always on charger**, and **rarely on battery**.

However the BIOS doesn't automatically apply charging threshold.
You need to manually to it in BIOS or OS.
In your case, I do not know how and why did it apply charging threshold,.